# java heap space error from Wuala

Tags: java, linux, heap-memory

I'm using Wuala (www.wua.la) but it keeps terminating on me every few hours with an error titled `java heap space` and this is what it says in the details:

```
Build: Linux64 165
Loader: 2013-01-11
App:    Domain Application, user: reggler ([6657,21160,11])
    (Common Application Linux64 165), Olympus
Date:   30.08.2014 11:35:39 PDT
OS: Linux 3.13.0-34-generic amd64 unknown
Java: 1.7.0_65-b32  Oracle Corporation
Memory: 480.5 MB max    30.3 MB free    480.5 MB total
Assertions active: yes
Default Locale: en_CA
Local Host: regDesktopHome/127.0.1.1
Running for: 3h 53min


Reporting thread: Thread[main,9,main]
obf.ey: Java heap space
    at obf.b.uncaughtException(Z:78)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1986)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.rehash(TLongIntHashMap.java:181)
    at gnu.trove.impl.hash.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:388)
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.doPut(TLongIntHashMap.java:222)
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.put(TLongIntHashMap.java:198)
    at obf.Ia.d(Z:46)
    at obf.Id.b(Z:78)
    at obf.If.c(Z:211)
    at obf.HH.a(Z:71)
    at obf.HF.kW(Z:254)
    at obf.HF.a(Z:225)
    at obf.JW.b(Z:37)
    at obf.Aq.Da(Z:140)
    at obf.Aq.run(Z:130)

--------------------------------------------

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.rehash(TLongIntHashMap.java:181)
    at gnu.trove.impl.hash.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:388)
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.doPut(TLongIntHashMap.java:222)
    at gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongIntHashMap.put(TLongIntHashMap.java:198)
    at obf.Ia.d(Z:46)
    at obf.Id.b(Z:78)
    at obf.If.c(Z:211)
    at obf.HH.a(Z:71)
    at obf.HF.kW(Z:254)
    at obf.HF.a(Z:225)
    at obf.JW.b(Z:37)
    at obf.Aq.Da(Z:140)
    at obf.Aq.run(Z:130)


==================================================

java.lang.Exception: stack where this report was generated
    at obf.ajU.fv(Z:324)
    at obf.ajU.<init>(Z:140)
    at obf.ajU.<init>(Z:90)
    at obf.aae.<init>(Z:39)
    at obf.aml.c(Z:775)
    at obf.aml.a(Z:341)
    at obf.aml.k(Z:191)
    at com.wuala.platform.Wuala.launch(Z:25)
    at com.wuala.loader3.Loader3.startInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.wuala.loader3.Loader3.openRunningInstanceOrStartNew(Unknown Source)
    at com.wuala.loader3.Loader3.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.wuala.loader3.Loader3.main(Unknown Source)
```

Can I fix this somehow or is this a bug in the application?

**ANSWER**
In case someone searches for this, the answer I got back from the Wuala support reads:

> Thank you for your email.
>
> You can increase the Java heap space memory in your preferences.
>   Please open Edit -> Preferences -> General and increase the Memory
>   limit. If you have 512 MB now, I would suggest allowing 1 GB of
>   memory.
>
> We hope Wuala suits your needs. If you have any further question,
>   please do not hesitate to contact us.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Zoran Markich Wuala Support Team

Comment: Do you have any control over the size of the heap that wuala allocates?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as it is phrased, it's not a programming question but a question about the configuration of a hosting platform. If there is a programming question in here, please rephrase, add source code that illustrates your question, etc.

Comment: Please use the option to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

That happens because the application does not have enough memory at its disposal to function. Probably the product does not do garbage collection properly, or could be any other issue.

I am curious if you would be able to solve the issue with JVM arguments while launching the application.

Anyways, I recommend that you post to the Community Forum of Wuala and you are expected to get a response faster. There is already a question, I don't know how relevant to your problem https://support.wuala.com/?bbp_search=java+heap+space&lang=en

Comment: I already tried that but the forum says **User registration is currently not allowed.** Thus I came here to ask...?

Comment: They can only help you. Try reaching them either via community forum or  their social media sites. They might have to tweak some stuff for you on the server side. Tweet them with the ERROR, they might reply you faster (since twitter is a bit more revealing than forum).